# React Navigation passing user data to all routes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

how can i pass user data to all routes as props?
I want to access user data in the form of props.user on all pages.

Maybe this is not the best way and you can share if there is a better way.

I'm using react native firebase auth plugin and getting user data like below.

```js
export default function RootNavigation() {
  // User auth state
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  // Stacks
  const authStacks = [...];
  const mainStacks = [...];
  const stacks = user ? mainStacks : authStacks;

  const onAuthStateChanged = useRef();
  onAuthStateChanged.current = async (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const authSubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged.current);
    return authSubscribe;
  });

  return isLoading ? (
    <SplashLoading />
  ) : (
    <Stack.Navigator
      headerMode="screen"
      screenOptions={screenOptions}
      initialRouteName="Landing">
      {Object.entries({...stacks}).map(([key, stack]) => (
        <Stack.Screen key={key} {...stack} />
      ))}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access data using [useNaviagtionState](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/), but It's very bad approach. You should use global storage or React Context. I recommend you to use some storages like mobx or redux, if your app is small you can also use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Comment: Thank you for reply

Comment: i will use mobx